# Is there a way to reset all my stats?

Tags: battlefield-3

And I mean all stats. Including unlocks, dogtags etc.  And I want to do this without re-buying the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present, it does not appear that there is a way to reset any stats.

The forums seems to indicate that the only way to do it is to be caught hacking and then get your stats reset by DICE. However, there is no guarantee that they wouldn't just ban you instead.

BF3 is different to BF:BC2, where you could have different profiles on the same account.

Answer (score 7):

Now, with [Battlefield 3 Premium](http://www.battlefield.com/battlefield3/1/premium), your can reset you Score/Minute, Kills/Deaths, and Wins/Losses stats.

Comment: this should be voted up and put as the answer now with Battlefield Premium out on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try using a "stat padding exploit".
They did wipe/reset stats of those who did use those kind of exploit in the past. 
But I wouldn't recommend doing that!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on other consoles, but this is kind of possible with xbox 360 if you don't mind using a different account(hint: free if you are using the family plan).

1. With the profile you activated Battlefield with(or bought an online pass) download the online pass to an xbox harddrive.
2. Create a new profile on that harddrive.

You should now be able to use that online pass with your new account. It's also completely possible to later copy your online pass to a thumbdrive along with that profile and play in two locations at once with one online pass. (one with your old gamertag and the other with your new gamertag)

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way.

1. Go to the ps3 home screen
2. Go to the Game submenu
3. Go to Game Data Utility
   (If you have a memory card in you might have to go to Memory Card Utility)
4. Scroll down to battlefield 3
5. Press triangle
6. Select delete
7. Select yes
8. Go back to the ps3 home screen
9. Go to game submenu
10. Go to Game Saved Utility
11. Scroll down to battlefield 3
12. Press triangle
13. Select delete
14. Select yes
15. Start battlefield game and have fun!! :)

WARNING: If you do this, it deleted all the battlefield 3 stats and saves. It deletes your Career, Multiplayer, Co-Op, Unlocks, Dog Tags, and I think your expansion packs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

1. Make a new account on your PS3 Home screen.
2. Log into the PlayStation Network with a different PSN account.
3. Launch BF3 and start over.

EA recently discontinued 'Online Pass' and removed the requirement from older games (including BF3). Therefore you will NOT be required to buy a new copy.